# Text Box Control Validation In Gridview inside UpdatePanel c# ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a **gridview** in which one of the column contains **Text Box** Control

I want to **Validate** the Text entered by the user as **AlphaNumeric** and **Space** only

Allowed--> **a** to **z**, **A** to **Z**, **0** to **9** and **space**

I want to validate it using **Javascript**

**Platform ASP.Net 2.0, C#**

What i have tried till now...

<**script type="text/javascript**">

```
  function IsValidCharNum(event) {
      var KeyBoardCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      if ((KeyBoardCode < 96 || KeyBoardCode > 123) && (KeyBoardCode < 65 || KeyBoardCode > 90) && (KeyBoardCode < 48 || KeyBoardCode > 57) && (KeyBoardCode < 32 || KeyBoardCode > 32)) {
          return false;
      }
      return true;
  } </script>
```

onkeypress="return IsValidCharNum(event)" of textbox(without gridview & update panel) it is working

Comment: Could you post what you have tried until now, so that we can help where you're getting struck.

Comment: Try [`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: you better try something and ask for the help instead of asking for the answer directly. Use regular expression

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RegularExpression Validator` like this :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="REValphaOnly" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter only alphanumeric." ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

More Info :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/472728/RegularExpressionValidator-In-ASP-NET

Comment: he wants to do it with javascript !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling javascript on textbox's keyup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateText(i) {
            if (/[^0-9a-bA-B\s]/gi.test(fieldname.value)) {
                alert("Only alphanumeric characters and spaces are valid in this field");
                fieldname.value = "";
                fieldname.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>


<asp:TemplateField >
      <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup ="ValidateText(this);"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Not working....but i was able to validate it using another script but in a simple textbox(without gridview and update panel)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
      function IsValidCharNum(event) {

          var KeyBoardCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

          if ((KeyBoardCode < 96 || KeyBoardCode > 123) && (KeyBoardCode < 65 || KeyBoardCode > 90) && (KeyBoardCode < 48 || KeyBoardCode > 57) && (KeyBoardCode < 32 || KeyBoardCode > 32)) {

              return false;

          }

          return true;

      }
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Finally created a right function to get the validation done

page.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function IsValidCharNum(event) {

      var KeyBoardCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;

      if ((KeyBoardCode < 96 || KeyBoardCode > 123) && (KeyBoardCode < 65 || KeyBoardCode > 90) && (KeyBoardCode < 48 || KeyBoardCode > 57) && (KeyBoardCode < 32 || KeyBoardCode > 32)) {

          return false;

      }

      return true;

  }
```

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="return IsValidCharNum(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

working with gridview and updatepanel both